# How to access image with JavaScript in Ruby On Rails Project assets?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem accessing image file from Ruby On Rails projects `app/assets/images/dir/image.jpg`

It's showing nothing on image box in a browser.
Locally on development environment run its shows.
In my code on a local machine, I am using relative path `'/assets/dir/'+image.jpg`  and this working locally ok.

I can open image on '`http://localhost:3000/assets/dir/ih4modxp4i4-jakob-owens.jpg`'   but online on production nothings showing '`http://xxx.62.xx.127/assets/dir/horuo-9ghiw-vincent-guth.jpg`'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not looking at the same image

Comment: So is `images/` part of the path or not?

Comment: Can you show your actual code? The usual fix for this is that you need to create a **template** for the javascript file - e.g. `something.js.erb`. This way, the path to the image can be resolved with regards to the asset pipeline.

Comment: ...Assuming that's the issue. Or maybe you simply don't have the images stored on the production server for some reason??

Comment: @tgdn this is just sample of images, they exist both.

Comment: @ChrisG yes that's the part of the path but in rails, you don't need to put that in a path, I tried with and without. Because on local dev its works without.

Comment: @TomLord I have javascript file with image names ass array and this works well on local development. https://codeshare.io/aJdoNy

Comment: @zire Like I said, the issue is probably (?) that in production you have enabled the **asset pipeline**. This means your files will be **fingerprinted** - i.e. have random strings appended to their names. [Read the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) on how to generate links to your files. Like I said above, the trick is to generate your `js` file via a ruby template - i.e. write it as a `.js.erb` file. (Or alternatively, disable the asset pipeline!)

Comment: Note also that public images can also be placed (unsurprisingly) in the `public/` folder. These will not be compiled, so can be referenced directly by the filename. However, images placed here will *always* be accessible (e.g. without logging in) - so don't misuse it. For example, you'll probably already have stuff relating to `4xx` error pages in the `public` folder.

Comment: @TomLord you are correct it was a problem with fingerprinted file names inside public dir.  They have random names,  so I need to make additional functionality to read newly generated names after recompiling assets. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first in here is that when you deploy to something like Heroku or you run the `rake assets:precompile`, it will add a token to every asset on your rails app(css,js,images,fonts), it's for caching purposes

This do not happen at development, so to make it work you need to first update the name of the `js` file to `something.js.erb` and then whenever you need the path for an image, you can now embed ruby on JS, so something like:

```
var imagePath = "<%= asset_path('image.png') %>";
```

This also work for coffee script as well, just make the proper arrangements! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you use webpack, it will precompile the image folder in assets, so the final path of the image will be without "image".
The following path
"localhost:3000/assets/**images**/location.png"
turns into
"localhost:3000/assets/location.png"

Maybe this will be a help :)

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the file config/environments/production.rb and changing this line:

```
 config.assets.compile = false
```

to this:

```
 config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: This will slow your application down.